# Fetch data from internet on App install android

Tags: android, installation

I developed an app which fetches a website data. Now the app will work only when the internet is available. But I want to add some content to the app for viewing in offline mode. So I want to know is it possible to fetch data from internet on installation time?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can consider downloading your data on first launch.

Comment: Thanks Nickolai
I will consider that